# How do you store a paragraph in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

i am building a site, that includes the user submitting comments. Now, want to save the different comments.. i read a bit about Linq to SQL and ADO.. they all talk about storing small bits of information like names, emails, passwords etc. But whats the most efficient way to save messages (which will be incorporated to a page like in youtube) at the end?

Comment: Is encoding/culture an issue here?

Comment: @Caspar: Why should it be an issue?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen depending on the the characters you want to store nvarchar or varchar might make a difference.

Comment: @Caspar: Is there a benefit to using the non-`n` variant of text datatypes?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen nvarchar takes more space than varchar nvarchar is limited to 4000 while varchar is limited to 8000 chars

Comment: @Caspar: The benefit of not having to worry about outdated character encodings outweights the space inefficiency in by far the most applications. I think one should have a really, really good reason for sticking to old character encodings before doing so.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen, agreed, that was why I was asking if it was an issue ;)

Comment: @Caspar: Actually `nvarchar(MAX)` is limited to about two gigabytes of data.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen oops.... excuse me for being stupid...  Thanks for the info.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think comments on a webpage still count as "small bits". Just make sure your database field has enough space (`nvarchar(MAX)` if supported, otherwise `text` or `ntext`, depending on your database of choice)

I don't think you need to start considering other methods of accessing data unless you have dozens of kilobytes of data per object, or a very large number of objects per page.

Comment: should i use string builder..or other encoding method..to prevent string from being counted as an object?

Comment: @Dmitry: I have no idea what you're trying to say. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way. You also want to html encode your message before you insert it into a database to avoid unwanted sql injections. Linq doesn't have such problems since it uses parameters to insert your text.

You should prefer paramater based insertion of text over embeded sql + encoding.

Comment: I don't think you should HTML encode anything in a database, you'll want to do encoding on the output side so it's easy to change your formatting/filtering afterwards.

Comment: You should always use a parameter-based approach (versus embedded SQL).  So encoding is not necessary.

Comment: Even with paramet based sql, you still need to scan and check for XSS and other such annoying attack vectors. I would use nvarchar so to be ready for i18N.

Comment: You do *not* want to encode before storing, you want to encode before display, i.e. after you bring it back from the database and before you embed it into a page. This has three advantages - 1) You're not limiting yourself to where it gets output, for example if you HtmlEncode you're not going to be able to use it in RSS, where XmlEncoding rules are different and 2) if the encoding function has a bug and is patched you'll get the patch, rather than have to go through the database, unencode then re-encode and 3) easier to search. Always encode at the point of rendering.

Answer (score 1):

In times gone by, you would use the deprecated **Text** datatype, but it will be removed in the next version, so the recommendation is to use **varchar(max)**.

Comment: my recommendation is, he have to use nvarchar(max)

Comment: Text is already deprecated, and has been since SQL Server 2005.  What you mean is that Text will be removed in the next version.

Comment: @Muhammad: whether you use UCS-2 (nvarchar) or not (varchar) is a different issue - some recommend always opting for unicode (opting for the lowest common denominator, if you will) and some recommend choosing the type according to the circumstances. Either way, setting the maximum storage size to 'max' is the recommended way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `text` datatype in MSSQL database. You can use it for a comments. Then in program, it's just a common string.

Edit: Since `text` is going to be deprecated, just use `varchar(max)` as others say.

Comment: text will be deprecated in the next version of Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ntext` datatype also. I use that for text.

Comment: Microsoft recommends to use `nvarchar(MAX)` instead of `ntext`.